# FindWindow with partial window title (Windows, C)

Tags: c, windows, findwindow

Is there any API similar to FindWindow() but that searches the windows by partial title?
The reason is that I need to the handle to a window that has a fix part on the title but the other part changes constantly.
So for example the window title could be:

DataBase read: XYDB

or

DataBase read: WZDB

in the examples the fix part is "DataBase read:"

Code appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

An example using EnumWindows:

```
BOOL CALLBACK WorkerProc(HWND hwnd, LPARAM lParam) {
    static TCHAR buffer[50];

    GetWindowText(hwnd, buffer, 50);
    if(_tcsstr(buffer, "window name goes here")) {
        // do something with hwnd here
        return FALSE;
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

And then call it like this:

```
EnumWindows(WorkerProc, NULL);
```

Comment: How can I pass a changing title to that function? I mean, the windows that i need to get the handle of can have up to 4 different titles with fix parts. So the "window name goes here" can take 4 different strings.

Comment: Never mind... i didn't read the code correctly before. Let me try it